# Sending email in app backend and getting blocked

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, backend

My app lets the users send details to our server using Java mail api , for which I am using my developers email and password. The problem is that google blocks the emails saying ‘ somebody is using your email’. Which server’s email and password account should be created at the javaMail backend to allow all users to send their details using my developers account for further processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get it straight. You want to use email to send data to your server ?
Why don't you send an http request with the data and do all the email handling on the server side. That way only one user (location, IP, etc..) uses the email.

Comment: I’m using my developers email to send email to another email. Process: The app user signs in using his email , he clicks on his required urls , those urls are uploaded on firebase server and then the links are forwarded using my developers email to the email of destination company who then processes those urls. At this point , google complains that your email address is being accessed by another device which is obviously the intended idea as it’s being by done at the backend using javamail api.

Comment: Update: I’m going to use third party to send email from my app as google is security blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new Gmail dedicated for this task as gmails serve as a smtp server.
And send the email from there to another email.

FYI: If it's some kind of a contact email, I suggest you popup the user default email client with some preset data. 
That way the user feels the most comfortable and you don't need an email server.

Comment: I made a separate email for this but google smartly somehow linked it to my other addresses. I get the message that somebody is using your email and password and the google security blocks it. However, I want that anyone can use it.The email has a list of urls that has to be forwarded to another company through email. It doesn’t make sense if the user sends it himself, that’s why the apps sends it.